# Display more posts on same page with Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I am screwing around with an image uploader build with python and flask. I have it up and running on my VPS here

```
http://107.170.119.38/
```

The application displays the first 25 images just fine, but anything after the 25th image does not get displayed anywhere. I am trying to add a button that would allow me to display the next 25 images from. Here is a sample of my code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_more_pics():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select filename, label from pics order by id desc limit 25')
    more_pics = [dict("filename": row[0], "label": row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('upload.html', more_pics=more_pics)

def upload_pic():
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    label = request.form['label']
    try:
        extension = file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    except IndexError, e:
        abort(404)
    if file and check_extension(extension):
        # Salt and hash the file contents
        filename = md5(file.read() + str(round(time.time() * 1000))).hexdigest() + '.' + extension
        file.seek(0)  # Move cursor back to beginning so we can write to disk
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], filename))
        add_pic(filename, label)
        gen_thumbnail(filename)
        return redirect(url_for('show_pic', filename=filename))
    else:
        # Bad file extension
        abort(404)
else:
    return render_template('upload.html', pics=get_last_pics())


@app.route('/show')
def show_pic():
    filename = request.args.get('filename', '')
    t = (filename,)
    cur = g.db.execute('select label from pics where filename=?', t)
    label = cur.fetchone()[0]
    return render_template('upload.html', filename=filename, label=label)

# Return a list of the last 25 uploaded images
def get_last_pics():
    try:
        cur = g.db.execute('select filename, label from pics order by id desc limit 25')
        filenames = []
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            filenames.append({"filename": row[0], "label": row[1] or ''})
        return filenames
    except:
        return []
```

and in the jinja2 template file:

```
<input type="button" value="Get More Pics" onclick="{{ more_pics }}">
    <ul>
        {% for pic in more_pics %}
        <li class="thumb">
        <a href="{{ url_for('show_pic', filename=pic.filename) }}"><img class="thumb" src="{{ pic_path('thumb2_'+pic.filename) }}"></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

all in all I can't figure out how to get the get_more_pics() function to display the next 25 images. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You include `limit 25` in your query. That will always limit you to the first 25 results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `offset` parameter to your SQL:

```
select filename, label from pics order by id desc limit 25 offset 0
```

You'll have to pass it into your SQL, as it will be 0 for the first page, then 25, then 50, etc. Probably better to break that 25 out into a parameter rather than hard-coding it, and calculate offset as the product of page and limit.

Also, bear in mind that LIMIT and OFFSET don't necessarily work with all databases, although they do work with SQLite and MySQL, the syntax can vary. E.g. for Oracle: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php.

An alternative is to use a slightly higher-level approach, such as an ORM.

Comment: Thanks. That works when I run it in command prompt but I just can't seem to get it to display results in my template. argh!!

Comment: If this works then you probably have a problem somewhere else. Maybe accept this answer and ask your next question, possibly posting a link to source code if it's a public project?